# response = requests.get error when URL is not reachable

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

I am trying to write a script and part of it has to check if a URL is available or not. The problem is that when I get a reply back 200,404, etc the program works fine and I can handle the reply but when the URL is not reachable, the program goes into the error below.
This is part of the code:

```
response = requests.get(url)
print (response)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python\lib\socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03EC9970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Is there a workaround to this?
If I can set the script to print a line like URL not available and exists will be great.

Comment: So just [catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)? See the [*Errors and Exceptions* section](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions). Did you try this yet, did you have issues locating what exception to catch?

Comment: Have you considered catching and handling the exception?

Answer (score 4):

Just [catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). The [*Errors and Exceptions* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions) of the `requests` documentation indicates you should be able to catch the [`requests.ConnectionError` exception](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.ConnectionError) here:

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
except requests.ConnectionError:
    print("Can't connect to the site, sorry")
else:
    print(response)
```

Quick demo with a non-existing hostname:

```
>>> import requests
>>> try:
...     response = requests.get("http://no_such_site_exists.imsure")
... except requests.ConnectionError:
...     print("Can't connect to the site, sorry")
... else:
...     print(response)
...
Can't connect to the site, sorry
```